# Using +0 in order clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column "available" which either returns "yes" or for instance "30 min". 
To sort this table we have found out that this works as intended where "Yes" comes first, and the "30 min" comes after.
`order by   available + 0 asc` 
Even though this works we do not know why we have to put +0 to the column. Can someone elaborate?

Edit: This is an example on a query
Note that all where clauses are not here, and the if(x is null) is to return something if there is no result aka null value.

```
select distinct r.rname, if(b.stime is null, 'Yes', 'Yes') as available, r.mperson
from Rooms r left outer join Bookings b using (rname)
union all
select b.rname, concat(minute(timediff(b.etime, '$sdate')), ' min') as available,      r.mperson
from     Bookings b inner join Rooms r using(rname)
order by    available + 0 asc, rname asc
```

Comment: Can you provide the table structure and the simplest query you're running that demonstrates the problem? Otherwise everything is just guessing.

Comment: That would treat the column as numeric. No idea how that applies to "Yes" and "30 min", but I would not rely on that behaviour. Try to convert more explicitly.

Comment: "yes" and "30 min" don't really fit together... an integral column with "0" and "30" would be better (and probably a million times faster to process)

Comment: It implicitely converts the `available` column to a numeric value. My guess is that this is an ugly hack to work around a bad data model where a number is stored in a `varchar` column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're implicitely converting the `available` value to a number, as you can see by trying

```
select "30 minutes" + 0; ==> returns 30
select "2 hours" + 0; ==> returns 2
select "yes" + 0; ==> returns 0
```

This makes `"yes"` (or any string not starting by a number) the first returned value instead of the last one.

This *does* change the order but this feels hacky and is less efficient than using a pure numeric field (which could be indexed).

More generally you always should define your schema such as to have precise non polymorphic fields.

Comment: On other platforms, `select "yes" + 0` will make the dbms complain about the column "yes" not existing. `select 'yes' + 0` will make the dbms complain about invalid input.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' This is MySQL. It lets you do more things, including the ones you shouldn't.

Comment: That was kind of my point. The reason the "solution" feels hacky to you is because it's not valid SQL on most platforms.

Comment: There are other reasons it feels hacky, including the facts it's unclear, unmaintanable, unindexable and non extensible.